# Why is a SELECT grant needed for an UPDATE statement on a table? (Error 1143)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

`myuser@'%'` has `UPDATE` and `INSERT` grants on `table1`.

I tried to run this `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 'blahblah' WHERE id = 123;
```

I got this error:

> SELECT command denied to user 'myuser'@'localhost' for column 'id' in table 'table1'

... and error code 1143.

Of course, I understand that the particular `UPDATE` I was trying to run needs to pick just the particular row I want, probably using the equivalent of a `SELECT` statement "under the hood" so to speak, to find the row identified by id = 123, but it doesn't seem right that I should need the `SELECT` grant when I'm not doing an explicit `SELECT`.

Can someone help me understand the logic that calls for a `SELECT` grant for this very common sort of `UPDATE`?

Comment: What grants do you currently have?  In particular, are they at the table level, or at the column level?

Comment: @RickJames The DB user has `UPDATE` and `INSERT` grants on the table level of `table1`.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst I can't find anything official to back this up (I will keep trying) I guess a user with `UPDATE` but not `SELECT` permissions could brute force their way into knowing the values in the table without having `SELECT` permissions

lets say the user runs the following query

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyCol = 'Something' WHERE Id = 1
```

and it returns that it successfully updated a row

and then the user runs

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyCol = 'Something' WHERE Id = 2
```

and so on (they could write a loop using front end or database code to try a range of Ids quickly)

This tells the user which values for Id exist in the table without them having `SELECT` permissions (and this example could be applied to other columns in the table)

Comment: I like this explanation. I was looking for an explanation in manuals for DBMSes such as MariaDB, Oracle, PostgreSQL - they all mention that you need the `SELECT` grant on the table or the specific columns referenced in the `WHERE` clause, but they don't seem to explain the reason behind this design.

Answer (score 1):

The important part is in the error message:

> SELECT command denied to user 'myuser'@'localhost' **for column 'id' in table 'table1'**

If you try `UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 'blahblah';` (without the selector `WHERE id = 123`); you will get no error message and the query will succeed.

This is due to the fact, that the `SELECT` privilege can not be treated 1:1 as a **read** privilege. It is actually the privilege to **select** rows from a table, either for the sake of updating them or for the sake of returning them.